# position of element screwed in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

For once, ff and ie comply. But in this instance chrome doesnt like it.

We have a field, with autosuggest attached, that appears after x amount of letters. Cannot really put a demo on fiddle, as its db driven.
However here is the css

```
.suggestionsBox {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 70px 0px 0px 146px;
    width: 207px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;    
    color: #000;
    box-shadow:-1px -1px 7px #ccc, 1px 1px 7px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-1px -1px 7px #ccc, 1px 1px 7px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow:-1px -1px 7px #ccc, 1px 1px 7px #ccc;
}

.suggestionList {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.suggestionList li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.suggestionList li:hover {
    background-color: #ffffcc;
}
```

And screenpic of ff , ie chrome appearance. Any suggestions, I am usually bloody good with css. But this has me stumped.
[image]

As requested here is html for this element:

```
<div class="field"><label for="propertysuburb">Suburb </label> <input name="propertysuburb" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" size="50" type="text" class="medium" /></div>
                        <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                                &nbsp;
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: would it be possible to provide an example with the HTML and some hardcoded data?  really hard to diagnose without seeing all the actual elements affected by the css.

Comment: I believe a live demo is more helpful then screens here.  If we could inspect the actual page in chrome it would have better chances of leading to an answer.  Without being able to see how chrome is rendering the elements its difficult to suggest a solution

Comment: Thanks Derek, yeah a live demo would be good, but then its a private project, and really dont want to share links on the WWW. I agree, its like the blind leading the blind, but thought from what I have added on here, may get some suggestions, as often the most obvious is overlooked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the margin for the .suggestionsBox do? As an absolutely positioned element, I believe it will just ignore that.

The issue seems to be that you're not setting any top / bottom / left / right values to your absolutely positioned .suggestionsBox div; this leaves it up to the browser to determine where to put it.

Make sure your .field class has "position: relative;" on it, then add a "top: 20px;" and "right: 0px;" to your .suggestionsBox styles. Just adjust the top / right values if it doesn't line up correctly.

Comment: thanks russel, I guess my code is actually pissing in the wind, so to speak in terms of field position, relying more on fluidity to position the element than assigning a real world value, which then can have siblings attached to it, if that makes sense. Will set relative positioning, and implement versiosn of yours and @mingos ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off, a nitpick.

When using CSS3 with vendor prefixes, ALWAYS use the non-prefixed version last, otherwise you may (potentially) break something:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:-1px -1px 7px #ccc, 1px 1px 7px #ccc;
-moz-box-shadow:-1px -1px 7px #ccc, 1px 1px 7px #ccc;
box-shadow:-1px -1px 7px #ccc, 1px 1px 7px #ccc;
```

As for your problem: I can't see the CSS for the `.field` div, but I assume it has a positioning context set as well (probably `relative`), otherwise the `z-index` on `suggestionBox` wouldn't work, and judging by the screenshots, it does. Now, what you haven't set is the actual position. The `absolute` positioning context should place the box in the top left corner of its parent (obviously, that's why the parent needs a positioning context too). If you need it to start at the parent's bottom, you also need to add `top: 100%;` to your `.suggestionBox` properties.

I can't really see anything else that might be wrong here.

Comment: .form .field { width: 50%; float: left; } is the style attr. for field
This is part of a very complex form, and top:100% obviously naffs it up, because we dont set position either relative, fixed or absolute for field. Any other ideas.

Comment: If the container doesn't have a positioning context, than the absolute positioning on the element will rely on the container's parent, if it's positioned, or its paren't parent, etc., up to <body>. If you need the field to appear on the left, maybe you should put it in another container and float that?

Comment: I have now set fields position relative, and then positioned the suggestbox absolute off that. Works a treat thanks :)

Comment: No problem, mate, glad to be of help :).

Answer (score 1):

To debug something like this, I would slightly modify your back-end code so that the suggestion list remains fixed and open, regardless of typed input. Load the page, then open the developer pane in Chrome, go to the Elements tab, and use the "magnifying glass" icon to inspect the misplaced elements. Play with the styles panel to discover which attributes are causing the incorrect offset (don't forget to try things like absolute vs. fixed position of the element or its parents). Once you have an idea of where things are going wrong, see if the "fix" is benign in other browsers.

Comment: will give it a go, Ken thanks. I kind of know why its going tits up, just dont know of a fix, that wont adversely affect other field elements. I suppose, adding relative positioning to the parent element would make sense, but i think it would screw up the form in general, will have a play

Comment: It would certainly be curious if it worked in Safari but not Chrome. I'd check Safari to see if it's Webkit or Chrome specifically.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's most-likely a JavaScript issue.  The suggestion list is most likely placed programmatically (given the `position: absolute` it seems certain), so I'd look to that code.

If it's not a JavaScript issue, the other possibility is that the "position parent" of the absolute element differs.  Your CSS shows that the suggestion box is positioned absolutely, but we cannot see from your posted code what establishes the baseline for the position (how its nearest-positioned ancestor is defined).

One thing that can sometimes help with absolute positioning is to use the `top` style rather than the margin-top to move your absolutely-positioned element down.

Comment: good idea. Will check now, hadnt even considered a conflict arising from the js itself.

Comment: Actually, I doubt that. It depends on the implementation, granted, but I'd say this one SHOULD depend on CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mingos and @russelluresti

We have this fixed now:

css:

```
.suggestionsBox {
z-index: 2;
top: 59px;
right: 524px;
position: absolute;
margin: 69px 0px 0px 146px;
width: 207px;
background-color: #ffffff;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;  
color: #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:-1px -1px 7px #ccc, 1px 1px 7px #ccc;
-moz-box-shadow:-1px -1px 7px #ccc, 1px 1px 7px #ccc;
box-shadow:-1px -1px 7px #ccc, 1px 1px 7px #ccc;
```

}

and field :

```
.form .field { width: 50%; float: left; position:relative;}
```

Cheers Guys, perfect. I havent got Safari, but it works in the 3 I was interested in, and seems to be valid code now, which supports proper rules. Many thanks

Comment: Glad to have been of use. Don't worry about Safari, the differences between it and Chrome are next to nil since it's the same engine ;)